# System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i a testing my app . it is giving me error

```
System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod. Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.
```

i am trying to call a Batch apex class when this app is based on Google Calendar Api.thats why json response .but i am facing the above error unable to resolve.

```
@isTest public class TestBatchCleanGCalendars {

    static testMethod void testBatchJob() {

        GoogleTestHelper.createfullGSettings(10);
        GoogleTestHelper.createCampaigns();

        List<Campaign> campaigns = [Select Id, Name from Campaign];

        system.assertEquals(5,campaigns.size());

        GoogleTestHelper.createTestCalendars();

        GCalendarUtil.testResponse = GoogleTestHelper.returnGCalendarResp();
            BatchCleanGCalendars bJob = new BatchCleanGCalendars('Select Id, Name, CalendarId__c,CalendarQuery__c,FieldToDisplay__c from CalendarSettings__c');

        bJob.testResponse = '{'
+' "kind": "calendar#events",'
+' "summary": "Saarthak",'
+' "description": "",'
+' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:05.354Z",'
+' "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",'
+' "accessRole": "owner",'
+' "items": ['
+'  {'  +'  "kind": "calendar#event",'   +' "id": "c3gmu1me12tmujuifgmbrr33rc",'  +'  "status": "confirmed",'
+  ' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YzNnbXUxbWUxMnRtdWp1aWZnbWJycjMzcmMgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+'  "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:03.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:03.552Z",'   +' "summary": "GC Product Webinar - Jan 7, 2002",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },'   +' "organizer": {'
+'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'    +' "date": "2006-09-04"'   +' },'  +'  "end": {'   +'  "date": "2006-09-04"'   +' },'   +' "iCalUID": "c3gmu1me12tmujuifgmbrr33rc@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'    +' "useDefault": true'  +'  }'  +' },'  +' {'   +' "kind": "calendar#event",'   +' "id": "6se2vm8guhbh2tekc7scnpcudc",'  
+' "status": "confirmed",'   +' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NnNlMnZtOGd1aGJoMnRla2M3c2NucGN1ZGMgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+' "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.096Z",'   +' "summary": "User Conference - Jun 17-19, 2002",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },'   +' "organizer": {'
+'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'   +'  "date": "2007-02-12"'   +' },'   +' "end": {'    +' "date": "2007-02-14"'   +' },'   +' "iCalUID": "6se2vm8guhbh2tekc7scnpcudc@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'    +' "useDefault": true'   +' }'  +' },'  +' {'  +'  "kind": "calendar#event",'  +'  "id": "8of1l1ffqbfmm582und3q42k10",' 
+'  "status": "confirmed",'   +' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=OG9mMWwxZmZxYmZtbTU4MnVuZDNxNDJrMTAgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+' "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.707Z",'   +' "summary": "DM Campaign to Top Customers - Nov 12-23, 2001",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },' 
+'"organizer": {'   +'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'   +'  "date": "2006-07-10"'   +' },'   +' "end": {'    +' "date": "2006-07-21"'  +'  },'   +' "iCalUID": "8of1l1ffqbfmm582und3q42k10@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'   +'  "useDefault": true'   +' }'  +' }'
+' ]'
+',"nextPageToken": "CigKGjFhaW9oc25nZTFhZzBxYTY4bjZhOGlrdG5nGAEggICA0arZqecT"'
+'}';

 bJob.testResponse1 = '{'
+' "kind": "calendar#events",'
+' "summary": "Saarthak",'
+' "description": "",'
+' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:05.354Z",'
+' "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",'
+' "accessRole": "owner",'
+' "items": ['
+'  {'  +'  "kind": "calendar#event",'   +' "id": "c3gmu1me12tmujuifgmbrr33rc",'  +'  "status": "confirmed",'
+  ' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YzNnbXUxbWUxMnRtdWp1aWZnbWJycjMzcmMgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+'  "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:03.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:03.552Z",'   +' "summary": "GC Product Webinar - Jan 7, 2002",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },'   +' "organizer": {'
+'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'    +' "date": "2006-09-04"'   +' },'  +'  "end": {'   +'  "date": "2006-09-04"'   +' },'   +' "iCalUID": "c3gmu1me12tmujuifgmbrr33rc@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'    +' "useDefault": true'  +'  }'  +' },'  +' {'   +' "kind": "calendar#event",'   +' "id": "6se2vm8guhbh2tekc7scnpcudc",'  
+' "status": "confirmed",'   +' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NnNlMnZtOGd1aGJoMnRla2M3c2NucGN1ZGMgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+' "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.096Z",'   +' "summary": "User Conference - Jun 17-19, 2002",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },'   +' "organizer": {'
+'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'   +'  "date": "2007-02-12"'   +' },'   +' "end": {'    +' "date": "2007-02-14"'   +' },'   +' "iCalUID": "6se2vm8guhbh2tekc7scnpcudc@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'    +' "useDefault": true'   +' }'  +' },'  +' {'  +'  "kind": "calendar#event",'  +'  "id": "8of1l1ffqbfmm582und3q42k10",' 
+'  "status": "confirmed",'   +' "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=OG9mMWwxZmZxYmZtbTU4MnVuZDNxNDJrMTAgamg5NWRyMDhpNDdwZ3RkMzFmMzQ5Z25uZmdAZw",'
+' "created": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.000Z",'   +' "updated": "2013-03-26T10:17:04.707Z",'   +' "summary": "DM Campaign to Top Customers - Nov 12-23, 2001",'   +' "description": "null",'   +' "creator": {'   +'  "email": "riteshmehandiratta@gmail.com"'   +' },' 
+'"organizer": {'   +'  "email": "jh95dr08i47pgtd31f349gnnfg@group.calendar.google.com",'   +'  "displayName": "Saarthak",'   +'  "self": true'   +' },'   +' "start": {'   +'  "date": "2006-07-10"'   +' },'   +' "end": {'    +' "date": "2006-07-21"'  +'  },'   +' "iCalUID": "8of1l1ffqbfmm582und3q42k10@google.com",'   +' "sequence": 0,'   +' "reminders": {'   +'  "useDefault": true'   +' }'  +' }'
+' ]'
+'}';
        Test.StartTest();

        System.assertEquals(2,[Select count() from CalendarSettings__c ]);

               DataBase.executeBatch(bJob); 


        Test.StopTest();


    }
```

after completing Batch request in finish method i am calling one more Batch class.can any one please point me why i am getting this error when i am calling one Batch class in testmethod ?? please some one help

Answer (score 2):

While you can call batch class from another batch class, you afre allowed to call only one batch class from Test classes. Hence you are facing this error.

The alternative for this is to check in the finish method of the calling Batch class whether you are in a test context or regular context. You can do this using Test.isRunningTest().

Answer (score 0):

> System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod. Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.", Failure Stack Trace: "External entry point"

In the test class we can't send more than 1 batch so use only uses single batch or records up to 199.